# Breaking first line of text at some width using css

Tags: css

Is it possible to break a text at some width for the first line and no break for the second line?

for instance breaking the following text *"Is it possible to break a text at some width for the first line and no break for the second line"* like this First Line:-**Is it possible to break a text** Second line:-**at some width for the first line and no break for the second line"**

Comment: Have you tried [the first result from the internet](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-a-line-break-using-css)?

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible. There is nothing in your mere text content there, that CSS _could_ somehow "target" in the first place. And CSS can't really apply formatting to text itself either (with a few exceptions, stuff like ::first-letter, ::first-line, but those can't help you here), but only to elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an invisible (= without content, border or background) right-floated element before that text, with `height: 1em` and `width: calc(100% - 300px)` where you can adjust the  `px` value to the desired width of the first text line:

```css
.x {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px dotted #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
<p>Is it possible to break a text at some width for the first line and no break for the second line. Is it possible to break a text at some width for the first line and no break for the second line. Is it possible to break a text at some width for the first line and no break for the second line. Is it possible to break a text at some width for the first line and no break for the second line.</p>
```

Note: I created a very light border for the floated element to make it visible for demonstration purposes, but you can simply delete that border setting to keep the element invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You can put "Non breaking space" in the position of the spaces of the 2nd line. It will hold them together.

```
at&nbsp;some&nbsp;width&nbsp;for&nbsp;the&nbsp;first&nbsp;line&nbsp;and&nbsp;no&nbsp;break&nbsp;for&nbsp;the&nbsp;second&nbsp;line
```